# Cant get information from one page to another using PHP

Tags: php, html, select, post

I have two pages. One with the select boxes on and the send button. When the user chooses their options from the select boxes and clicks send it takes them to the second page which outputs their choices.

date_change.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
<?php
$day = array(range(1,31));
$month = array(range(1,12));
$year = array(range(2011,2020));
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Day:
<select >
  <?php foreach($day[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" name="day"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<br>
Month:
<select>
  <?php foreach($month[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" name="month"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<br>
Year:
<select>
  <?php foreach($year[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" name="year"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='send' name='send' />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Once the user makes their choices and clicks send it takes them to test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

Date Selected: <?php echo $_POST["day"];echo $_POST["month"];echo $_POST["year"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

However, even though it goes to the test.php page it doesnt show what the user picked. Any help?

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Five identical answers within a minute. Nice :D

Comment: @Stephan: Yeah, awesome!

Comment: Have you managed to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `name` attribute to your `<select>` tags instead of your `<option>` tags.

Also, you should change `<br>` to `<br />` for XHTML valid code.

Change you code to:

```
Day:
<select name="day">
  <?php foreach($day[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<br />
Month:
<select name="month">
  <?php foreach($month[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<br />
Year:
<select name="year">
  <?php foreach($year[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is your `<select>` elements which need the month/day/year name attributes, not their child options:

```
<select name="month">
  ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `name` attributes should be on the `select` elements, not their `option`s.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `name` attribute on the `<select>` element, not the `<option>`, like this:

```
<select name="day">
```

Answer (score 2):

The `name` attribute goes on the `select`, not each individual `option`.